# What is the color of a manga paper?

Tags: manga-production

The background color of a manga paper when scanned online is changed by the scanlators to white (#FFFFFF).

However, this is not the background color in an actual manga book. the color in the manga book looks little grayer in the paper.

What I am trying to do, is to publish a manga online with the same real background color.

- What is the best estimation of that white-gray color?
- What are the manga papers made of? They are not the same as a normal white printer paper.

Comment: Every paper will scan to be a different color (and thus, different hex code) based on the scanner and paper quality. Plus, not all manga will be printed on the same paper. Regardless of that, though, this is off-topic and would be better suited on a graphic design or manga writing forum, so I'm voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: @Eric I am trying to create a manga magazine and I need to know the background color of a usual shonen manga. an assumption of the color is fine. as long as it is very close to the real paper background color... my question perfectly fits in the manga-production category

Comment: @shnisaka Manga paper comes in all kinds of sizes depending on a publisher's specifications. The color of the paper does not matters as most pages in manga are monochrome (like with newspapers). Glossy paper is typically use for color pages as the colors come out better on that type of paper.

Comment: @shnisaka Note that we are discussing this question in chat here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8340058#8340058

Comment: @shnisaka as it stands now, your question is not a very good one and too localized to help anyone. In print, the color of the paper is determined by the paper stock used. You cannot find a specific color of a paper by the hex code. Print media goes by CMYK (Cyan Yellow Magenta Black) color, while media that appears on computers screen goy by RGB (Red Green Blue, Hex are RGB), because that's how colors are displayed by computers screens. However it you want to ask about the type of paper used for manga, that is a perfectly fine question and you can edit your current question to reflect that.

Answer (score 12):

The color varies *widely* based on multiple factors:

- Lighting
- Paper type (I'll get there in a minute)
- Scanner type and quality

Therefore, I can't 100% give you a color estimate (it could be anything from very light yellowish-gray to very dark gray).

---

As for paper types. There are also several types of paper that could be used for printing manga:

- Newspaper-like paper, which is thin and has a slight gray shade.
- Recycled paper, which is yellowish in composure and often has little "grains" in it.

There are probably a whole lot more, but that's the prominent two I know of.

Comment: The color also varies depending on the weight and thickness, if it's coated (books typically aren't coated, but photo books are), and if it's [acid-free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid-free_paper) (not as yellowing as non-acid-free papers). It's better to go to an actual printer for a sample and use that sample as reference.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: I also had this question, but I ended up having to make color combinations, print them out, and compare them to physical copies of manga I had. The closest color combination I was able to make was:
(R, G, B) = (238, 230, 201).